# Does powershell 5 class have access modifiers?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to control the access of members in Powershell classes? As the same way we do in c++ or C#. How can we write below C# class in Powershell

```
class Car
{
  private string engine;
  public string wheel_type;

  public void drive()
  {
  }
  private int change_engine(string new_engine)
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting in PowerShell 5.0, PowerShell adds class support.

Please note that PowerShell does not offer a private keyword though. 
You can, however, use the hidden keyword, which will hide the property / method from the intellisense by default (although it can be forced to appear) and the **Get-Member** cmdlet won't return the hidden members unless the **-Force** switch is used.

Here is a sample car class which demonstrate a bit of everything.

```
enum Engine {
    None
    V4
    V8
}

Class Car

{    
    static [int]$numberOfWheels = 4
    [int]$numberOfDoors
    [datetime]$year
    [String]$model
    [Engine]$Engine 

    car() {
    #Constructor ... optional
    }

    car([Engine]$Engine,$numberofDoors = 4 ) {
    #Constructor overload with default value... optional
    $this.Engine = $Engine
    $this.numberOfDoors = $numberofDoors
    }

    drive()
    {
    }

    hidden [int] change_engine([string] $new_engine) {
        return 0
    }
}


# Call to static property
[Car]::numberOfWheels

#Create Car object
$MyCar = New-Object Car([Engine]::V4,4)

#Call drive
$MyCar.drive()
```

**References**

[4syops - PowerShell classes (series of 4)](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-classes-part-1-objects/)

[Microsoft PowerShell docs: About Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-5.1)

[Sapien.com - Hidden keyword](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/03/18/hidden-sort-of-the-hidden-keyword-in-windows-powershell-5-0-preview/)